# Save first word in SMS message using Twilio Studio

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio, liquid-template

I'm working with Twilio Studio trying to get the first word from an SMS text message. The issue is that sometimes the word has a `:` or `;` appended.

**Example:** `TEST: This is a test`

I need the `TEST` alone, without the `:`.

I tried the [`truncatewords` filter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/user-guide/liquid-template-language#standard-filters), but `TEST:` was still returned.

`{{trigger.message.Body | split: " " | first |  truncatewords: 1 | downcase}}`

How is this done?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I'd just perform another `split` like:

`{{trigger.message.Body | split: " " | first |  split: ":" | first | downcase}}`